# Difference between a php session cookie and a plain cookie for handling users

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

I want to set a users session cookie using `javascript` lets name it `usertoken` with a value returned from the server during the login authentication process. No other data is stored, just that token value.

Every time the user loads a page or makes a request to the server. The server checks for the `usertoken` if its there, then validate, if its good let the user in, if not then access denied. (the process would require a db query)

---

PHP's Sessions still uses cookies to store the session id, so I don't see the clear advantage of using it aside from the fact that you can store user data inside the `$_SESSION` variable for easier calling in later visits (but that uses up server memory?)

---

So my question is, is there any difference with the cookie handling above and using php's session cookie `$_SESSION`? In terms of security and performance in high-scale traffic?

Comment: Well there is no other option than using the session , and yes its fine for large-scale website,  also if you only use cookie than you have to store in db as key .. which would be same

Comment: @NullPoiиteя so there is no security advantage when using sessions?

Comment: Well there are security advantage beacuse user dont know what is in session, while cookie can be easily seen  at browser

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. PHP Sessions is just an automated way to deal with cookies and session data. When you call session_start, PHP checks for the presence of a cookie with session_id to fetch the user data, but if it doesn't find any cookie, a new session id is generated and HTTP headers are set with a new one. PHP also offers some other functionality to deal with the session so you can set when the cookie expires, destroy the session and etc.

By default PHP stores session data in temporary text files, but you can customize it by writing your on adapter. Many applications uses PHP sessions but with data stored in a database.